# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activesupport

I migrated to 3.2.13 version of rails and I am getting this error, how do I get rid of this?

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.2.12)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.13) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 3.2.13) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

EDIT

```
sinatra (1.3.6)
  rack (~> 1.4)
  rack-protection (~> 1.3)
  tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
```

Comment: Did you update it by running `gem update rails`?

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile? Are there any gems in it with locked versions?

Comment: Have you tried `bundle update` as it suggests?

Comment: I installed rails version 3.2.13 also. I tried bundle update, it doesn't seem to help. I have attached the sinatra dependencies as seen in my Gemfile.lock file. I just don't need any direct dependencies on it, but still the bundler expects it to be there.

Answer (score 25):

For anyone who accidently comes to this link (at the time google served this page first); check out this post [Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem, updating Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858706/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-updating-rails-app)

My steps were run

```
gem update rails

rm Gemfile.lock
```

change my Gemfile to reference the version of rails i wanted

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

finally run

```
bundle install
```

I didn't try bundle update as @PistachioPony suggested but that might take the place of removing the lock file and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin with Rails 4 requires you to track master.  From the github page:

> We're currently working on 1.0.0, which as far as dependencies, moves
>   us from meta_search to Ransack and adds Rails 4 support. You can get
>   Rails 4 and 4.1 support by tracking master:

`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`

Also, make sure you ***DON'T*** use the [docs on the main page](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) because they are outdated for rails 4.   There are [updated docs for rails 4](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/0-installation.md) with master.

I'm not sure how much longer this answer will be relevant, so you should [check github](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) to see if things have changed before blindly tracking master. Also, note that tracking master usually means you will get development changes as they come.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your rails to 3.2.13 then also change your active support in the gemfile.lock to 3.2.13 then:

Run:

$ bundle update

shut down your server:

$ control c

Make sure in your terminal that ***you are in your project folder*** then:
restart your server:

$ rails server

refresh your browser

Answer (score 0):

go like this: `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'` in da gemfile