# Bundle installation error; active support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle-install

There seems some error during bundle! The following message seems to be seen after **bundle install**

```
C:\Users\Nir\Desktop\my projects\projectmeal>bundle install
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
    Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
    Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
    Resolving dependencies...........................
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
      In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
        activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)

      In Gemfile:
        carrierwave x86-mingw32 was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
          activesupport (>= 3.2.0) x86-mingw32

    easy_rails_money (~> 0.0.8) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 0.0.8, which depends
    on
          activesupport (~> 3.2) x86-mingw32

        elasticsearch-model x86-mingw32 was resolved to 0.1.9, which depends on
          activesupport (> 3) x86-mingw32

        factory_girl_rails x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.7.0, which depends on
    factory_girl (~> 4.7.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.7.0, which depends
    on
            activesupport (>= 3.0.0) x86-mingw32

        factory_girl_rails x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.7.0, which depends on
    factory_girl (~> 4.7.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.7.0, which depends
    on
            activesupport (>= 3.0.0) x86-mingw32

        rspec-rails x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.5.2, which depends on
          activesupport (>= 3.0) x86-mingw32

    Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
    the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

and when i try to run some rails command like **rake db:create** the following error is seen in terminal

```
C:\Users\Nir\Desktop\my projects\projectmeal>rake db:create
Could not find gem 'guard-rspec x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in
 your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

and the process continues.....

Comment: You installed ruby via? rvm?

Comment: Did you try to update rails ? [Check out this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16225564/4414956)

Comment: It look like dependency error.

Comment: @gates no i didn't used any rvm to install ruby...

Comment: @nuaky Thanks bro. I will check that out surely!

Answer (score 0):

If bundle says it cannot find compatible gem versions it's probably because it has nowhere to look. You're giving it version numbers, i.e. forcing it to take certain versions for each gem, or versions superior to X, or inferior to X.

Instead of :

```
  gem 'activesupport'
```

Try:

```
gem 'activesupport', '3.2.0'
```

Comment: Remove your Gemfile.lock before fire bundle install