# rails 4 and active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to install ActiveAdmin on a Rails 4 project, and am getting this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (4.0.0)
```

I've followed this example: [Active admin install with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4) and added activeadmin to the gemfile like so:

gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'

But still no go; same error.

Comment: AA is working well with Rails 4, see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17965030/978728

Answer (score 1):

Ah my mistake; I thought I didn't have to include all the others since I wasn't using them; but it's not ActiveAdmin that is having a problem with ActiveRecord but something that AA depends on:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2322

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version you are using Rails 4.1 or 4.0.

If yo are using Rails 4.0.X just use master and you are ready to go:

> gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

For Rails 4.1 you should use master and the following dependency branches:

> gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
>
> gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'
>
> gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
>
> gem 'formtastic', github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'

After that just

bundle install (or bundle update, if necessary)

and run

rails generate active_admin:install (if necessary) to install

Comment: great, thanks a lot. Require github path because it has not officially supported for Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`  in Gemfile