# Rails 4: activeadmin error message - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to use [activeadmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/documentation.html) for my rails project, so I added it to my **gemfile**.

```
 gem 'activeadmin'
```

and updated the bundle, but received this error message -

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.0.0.rc2) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (4.0.0)
```

I uploaded the project in github; this is the link of the **gemfile** - https://github.com/Mashpy/esl/blob/master/Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

#gem
 gem 'activeadmin'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

What am I doing wrong that is preventing me from adding activeadmin?

Answer (score 5):

Active Admin has a few other dependencies as well. Check this out [Active Admin install with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4).

Copy and paste all the gems (in the top answer) to your gemfile and you should not have any issues running bundle.

Answer (score 4):

You can update your bundle using -

```
bundle update
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

To make sure your configuration of the **gems** are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should upgrade these gems :

```
sass-rails ~> 3.2.3
coffee-rails ~> 3.2.1
```

References:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html