# Ruby on Rails Bundler activeadmin gem install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin, bundler, activeadmin

I am running into issues when trying to install the activeadmin gem. I am using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0.2.

Here is what I get when I run "bundle install" in my project directory:

```
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\RubyonRailsWorkspace\GroupSRailsProjectNew>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Updating git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
fatal: failed to open '/cygdrive/c/Users/Samuel/Desktop/RubyonRailsWorkspace/Gro
upSRailsProjectNew/C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_a
dmin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca/objects': No such file or directory

Retrying git clone --no-checkout "C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/cache/bundl
er/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca" "C:/Ruby200-x64/li
b/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-60d8be97ec2c" due to error (2/3): Bu
ndler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout
"C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b7
4efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca" "C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/ac
tive_admin-60d8be97ec2c"` in directory C:/Users/Samuel/Desktop/RubyonRailsWorksp
ace/GroupSRailsProjectNew has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory 'C:/Ruby200-x6
4/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777
a851e9f78b2ca'
```

This is what I get when I run "gem install activeadmin":

```
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\RubyonRailsWorkspace\GroupSRailsProjectNew>gem install activeadmin
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 3.2.16), actionpack 
(= 3.2.16); actionmailer requires actionpack (= 3.2.16); activeresource
requires activesupport (= 3.2.16); meta_search requires activesupport (~> 3.1),
actionpack (~> 3.1); activerecord requires activesupport (= 3.2.16); activemodel
requires activesupport (= 3.2.16), builder (~> 3.0.0); railties requires rack-s
sl (~> 1.3.2), rdoc (~> 3.4), activesupport (= 3.2.16), actionpack (= 3.2.16)
```

Here is my GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

#Use CarrierWave for File uploading
gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'mini_magick'

gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Admin Panel
#gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack", branch: "rails-4"
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
#gem 'i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/i18n'


# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'execjs'
# gem 'therubyracer'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the `bundle install` from [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), while had begun to run it from [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) shell, try to run from [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) shell, because I see you have mixed the native [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), and [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) path styles up.

Comment: Thank for the help! I simply used msysgit for "bundle install" and it worked. However, I still get the Gem::DependencyError when I run gem install activeadmin. This should not matter though since I installed it through the Gemfile correct?

Comment: @EighthEmperor does this work `gem install activeadmin`?

Comment: I have been told that I don't need to use gem install if I am installing it with Bundler. Is this correct?

Comment: @EighthEmperor bundle installs the published gems in the same manner. So just try to `gem install activeadmin`. Wheither it gives: `C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\RubyonRailsWorkspace\GroupSRailsProjectNew>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle`?

Comment: "gem install activeadmin" does not work for me but I have already installed it by using bundle install on my Gemfile. "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" is just a warning.

Comment: @EighthEmperor ok, which problem is kept?

Comment: Sorry I can't up vote you.. Using "bundle install" worked. There was no need to use "gem install activeadmin" since I installed using Bundler.

Comment: @EighthEmperor `gem install activeadmin` run is needed to check the proper installation, it is requirement of bundler, so, I dont understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The gem you are trying to install requires rails 3.2.* and you are using 4.0. Either downgrade rails or use anther gem.

Use this to install activeadmin for rails 4: [Active admin install with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4)

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: "rails4"
```

Comment: I read that the Rails 4 branch has been merged into master and I can use: gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin' just fine now.