# Rails 4 I can't install gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, meta-search

Hello I want to install these 
`gem 'activeadmin'`,
`gem "meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'`
 gems to my project but I got error like this

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    actionpack (4.0.2)

  In Gemfile:
    meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre) ruby depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0.alpha) ruby
```

How I can solve these problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [Active admin install with Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta_search doesn't support rails 4. So you're getting a conflict.

Suggest you have a look at [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) instead, which is basically a ground up rewrite of meta-search. If you're using rails 3, then you need to specify this in your Gemfile.

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'metasearch->ransack': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Just `gem ransack` should do it. No need to reference metasearch

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2) ruby depends on
        activerecord (~> 3.0.0.rc2) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (4.0.0)
Murat-MacBook-Pro:quick_blog

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      sprockets (<= 2.11.0, ~> 2.8) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby depends on
        sprockets (2.12.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (~> 3.0.0.rc2) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (4.0.0)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin has a few other dependencies as well. Check this out Active [Admin install with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4).

Copy and paste all the gems (in the top answer) to your gemfile and you should not have any issues running bundle.

Comment: Retrying git rev-parse rails4 due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git rev-parse rails4` in directory /Users/mkaya93/.bundler/cache/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/mkaya93/.bundler/cache/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'

Answer (score 0):

just put 
"meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'
before
gem 'activeadmin'
this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 gem 'devise',              github: 'plataformatec/devise'
gem 'responders',          github: 'plataformatec/responders'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack'
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
```

it's worked