# ActiveAdmin + Jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to use active admin gem but when i ran bundle it says i need jquery-ui-rails version 5.0.0 so i changed my gemfile to :

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Upon restart my server i'm getting this error in the browser

```
 File to import not found or unreadable: jquery.ui.all.
    Load paths:

      /.../.../.../.../app/assets/images
      /.../.../.../.../app/assets/javascripts
      /.../.../.../.../app/assets/stylesheets
```

Answer (score 0):

`jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0` has renamed the .js files used by ActiveAdmin.

Until Active Admin is updated, use the `4.2.1` version in your gemfile and re-bundle:

`gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'`

**Edit**: This has just been fixed. If you require `4.2.1` now, it will break as active_admin is referencing the new paths. You should remove jquery-ui-rails from your Gemfile completely and run:

`bundle update activeadmin` 
if you required 4.2.1 before.

Comment: Well another solution i found is to `//= require jquery-ui` in application.js and remove `@import "jquery.ui.all" ` from application.css.scss

Comment: it is not a good solution I think. Just remove it from your gemfile and rebundle as I explained in my answer.

Comment: As a note... it does not look like `jquery-ui-rails 4.2.1` is available now