# active admin in rails 4.0.0 DEPRECATION WARNING

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I am using active admin as given in [Active admin install with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426398/active-admin-install-with-rails-4) . gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin' is installing. 
 But still i am getting error after running `rails generate active_admin:install`.
The error is

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.0.4 will be dropped from Formtastic 4.0. invoke  devise
To use devise you need to specify it in your Gemfile. If you don't want to use devise, run the generator with --skip-users.
```

Comment: ya it is working sorry. I did not informed you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you did not install [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

You want to

a) install devise: `gem install devise`, and then run `rails generate active_admin:install`. This will create default AdminUser object.

b) use the hint from warning, and install activeadmin with `rails generate active_admin:install --skip-users`.