# Active admin install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have an error, when try to run command:

`rails g active_admin:install`

The error is:

> user@user1:~/projectX$ rails g active_admin:install
>             invoke  devise
>       /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6bde1f57ec5f/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb:21:in `rescue in install_devise': uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::Generators::DeviseGenerator::DependencyError (NameError)
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-6bde1f57ec5f/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb:19:in`install_devise'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`each'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`invoke_all'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in`invoke'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:277:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in`with_padding'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:133:in`_invoke_from_option_users'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`each'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`invoke_all'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in`'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:130:in`generate_or_destroy'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>         from /home/user/projectX/bin/rails:8:in`'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>         from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
>         from -e:1:in `'

Active admin and devise gems are installed. The only problem is when I generate active admin. I use Rails-4.1.8 and ruby-2.1.4.

Thanks for help and good day.

Comment: Take a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16805376/1290852

Comment: Thanks. I try this, but not work.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem in a new app; how did you fix?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the `gem 'devise'` to your Gemfile or directly using the cli

```
bundle add devise
```

or you need to run the install with the the `--skip-users` flag.

```
rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
```

Answer (score -1):

`activeadmin` gem (I mean latest version of gem on rubygems.org) still is not compatible with Rails 4.x.

Try to use use latest version of activeadmin from repository:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin', branch: :master
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn`t work. Same error message.

Comment: It's very strange. I can't reproduce your problem. Could you please provide full backtrace?

Comment: I reinstall my operation system and rvm two-three times, but not work.

Comment: Could you please provide your Gemfile? AA raise `DependencyError` exception if `devise` version isn't equal to ~> 3.2. May be you are using 3.1 for example.

Comment: i tried to change devise version, but  doesn`t work. I give you a link to pastebin with content to my Gemfile.
http://pastebin.com/EWxfLBrv

Comment: Look at (this script)[https://gist.github.com/maxd/2cf74ef11e1f0c53d9cf]. It should create new Rails app, install all gems locally and install AA. Try to run it.

Comment: Thanks, but the link is broken. Fix it please.

Comment: I remove rvm and install rbenv and everything is work. No idea what`s happening.

Comment: I have the same error.   Gems are right.   But getting this same dependency error.

Comment: Use rbenv, that helps to me.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me.

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2'
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.